# Keypress with delay, how to limit to only one execution of function call?

Tags: javascript, forms, timer, keyup

I'm setting up a form to lookup or create a new city record in a web app. I need the text field for the city to do the following:

1. Upon receiving text input, show a "spinner" indicating the computer is processing the input.
2. After the user has stopped typing for 1 second, send an ajax request to check the input.
3. Respond with the status (whether the input is valid).

I have this almost working but I have one major issue: the delay script I wrote works but after the delay is over it runs the rest of the function once per keyup that occurred during the delay. I would like it to only run once. Here's the code I'm working with (the console log events would be replaced with other function calls later):

```
$(function() {
  locationSelector.initialize();
});

var locationSelector = {

  initialize: function() {
    locationSelector.bindCityName $('input#city_name')
  },

  city: {
    status: function( status ) {
      console.log( "Status message: " + status );
    },
    error: function(message) {
      console.log("Error message: " + message );
    }
  },

  bindCityName: function(selector) {
    selector.on('keyup', function() {
      locationSelector.city.status('loading');
      var timer = null;
      if(timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
      }
      timer = window.setTimeout(
        function() { locationSelector.getCity( selector ); },
        1000
      );
    });
  },

  getCity: function(selector) {
    if( selector.val() == "" ) {
      locationSelector.city.error('Cannot be blank.');
    } else {
      console.log("AJAX REQUEST");
    }
  }
};
```

Why is the `getCity` function is being run once per keyup, and how can I fix that? Also, to be honest I'm very much a javascript novice, so I would appreciate any other suggestions on how to improve this code scaffold.

Thanks!

Comment: jfriend and dbaseman, thanks for your answers. Since you both gave essentially the same answer, I've picked dbaseman's since he was 1 minute sooner and has dramatically less rep. Upvote for both since they were both helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
var timer = null;  
if(timer) {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

*Timer* gets set to null, so it never gets cleared.  I'd suggest declaring *timer* at the top, above initialize, and then setting it to null only after you clear it, or after it gets executed.

Comment: Total js newb question, but if what does the syntax look like to move it up and keep it inside of `locationSelector`? Do I need to set it as a key and refer to it as `locationSelector.timer`, or... am I going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: No, just "timer" works as long as you're in a nested block, as you are.  Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the variable declaration for `timer` needs to be in a scope that lasts from one key event to the next.  As it is, it is a local variable that gets recreated from scratch on every key event so you're getting multiple timers going at once.

Move this:

```
var timer = null;
```

to the global scope or a higher scope that persists from one key event to the next.  You can also define the timer variable as a property of location selector if you want:

```
var locationSelector = {
// other properties defined here
    timer: null
}
```

Then, you can refer to it as `locationSelector.timer`.  I'd also suggest that when your timer actually fires that you should set `locationSelector.timer = null` since a timer is no longer active.

It also looks like you'll need to clear the `'loading'` status once you run the ajax.

And, your timer is set for 2 seconds, but you said you want to wait 1 second for no typing.

Comment: Re 2 seconds, that's a typo on my part, thanks for catching it! I've edited to fix.

Comment: @Andrew - FYI, I added another option to my answer that defines `timer` as a property of your `locationSelector` object.